# Не работает Автоформатирование в vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, настройка

Я установил через pip install yapf формартер для python в vscode. Но с помощью сочетания клавиш он не форматировал, никакие стили не использовал. Если напрямую писать в консоли yapf -i путь файла, то форматирование происходит. Уже все перепробовал, auto save, отключать расширения, сбрасывать сочетания клавиш, переустанавливать vscode с полной чисткой, даже без расширений не работает. В общие настройки json прописывал так

```
 ***"python.formatting.yapfPath": "C:/Users/user/Desktop/testPython/Python311/Scripts/yapf",
"editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",***
```

первую строчку и просто yapf пробовал.

Конкретно для того окружения где у меня находится файл с кодом, в файле json я прописал так:

```
***{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
        "--style",
        "",
        "--indent-width",
        "4",
        "--column_limit",
        "80"
    ]
}***
```

Честно говоря не знаю и что и думать помогите пожалуйста

Comment: также при нажатии сочетаний клавиш я вижу  надпись с низу где строка состояния formartting whith yapf, но буквально на долю секунды

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, у меня были указаны настройки в .style.yapf которые почему-то некорректно воспринимает формартер, а так как эти настройки находятся в корневой папке с проектом, который я не удалял, то соответственно все действия которые я делал до этого - бессмысленны.